# Silverlight - Examples of awesome demo applications NEEDED!

Tags: silverlight, user-interface, silverlight-2.0

At company I'm working, new project will be started soon. I'd like to use Silverlight 2.0 but I need to convince my CEO and Photoshop/AfterEffects guy for using Silverligt for upcoming project. These persons are - let's say - rather Flash / Apple oriented, but for me as a .NET developer Silverlight seems to be proper solution :-)

I have a list of advantages from developer's point of view but I need to show for these non-technical persons any working demos .

These applications could be business applications, but the most important features are:

- fancy graphics - not a developer manufacture,
- comfortable and interesting UI,
- functionalities which are difficult to implement in Flash

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a good old fashioned religious war. Why not toss in html 5 to the debate? just for fun, of course.

Comment: Meanwhile, in a large office high atop a building at One Microsoft Way in Redmond, WA, a top Microsoft executive is reading this and laughing to himself maniacally.

Comment: Steam Train versus Horse and Cart - which is better? Get with the 21st century and throw both techniques in the bin. (Oops - I see this is an old question!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that folks really like [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main):

[image: Quince Silverlight Application]
<sub>(source: [sparklingclient.com](http://files.sparklingclient.com/quince.png))</sub>

One of my favorites is [Centre des Usages](http://www.microsoft.com/france/entreprises/centre-des-usages/):

[image: Centre Des Usages Silverlight Application]
<sub>(source: [sparklingclient.com](http://files.sparklingclient.com/centredesusages.png))</sub>

Comment: I dunno, Quince seems pretty doable with straight HTML/javascript.

Comment: You must have crazy good javascript skills :)  Did you hover over/click any of the buttons?  I'd love to see a jQuery/js app that did does this kinda stuff and looks this good!

Comment: Nice examples. This is more or less the type of examples I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Telerik have a couple of nice looking [demos](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/) of their controls

Comment: It looks impressive but I'm afraid it could be too heavy for me.

Answer (score 3):

This silverlight [showcase](http://silverlight.net/showcase/Default.aspx) will probably have something you can use

Comment: The issue is that it seems like ad-hoc demos, not real life software. Also, the quality of them vary A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

There are some killer visual effects in SL3:
http://blogs.msdn.com/henryh/archive/2009/03/20/mix09-the-gratuitous-graphics-demo.aspx

That demo is pretty awesome.  Be sure to mention out of browser support, which you can't do in flash (though I understand other adobe technologies support OOB).  Other posts on stack overflow have pointed to there being more 3rd party controls for SL than Flash but I don't have any stats to back it up.

Comment: That's a pity, demo is temporarly unavailable :(

Comment: Download the source, it builds easily and runs (on my machine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you don't need Demo's of fancy graphics or comfortable and interesting UI's. Since this would be by design and would be implementable in Flash or Silverlight.

Surely things like the fact that existing programmer knowledge can be extended into the rich UI because you can reuse your .Net skills would be the key thing. Being able to deliver functionality rather that just "flash"....

The showcase above is quite good, but the argument is still going to come back from the people who are used to using flash by saying "Yea, but we could do that in flash".

You need to show them what additional functionality Silverlight would allow for which you are battling to implement using flash. The down side is that if you can not do that, and you have a company with resources that is already trained in building things in Flash, you may be better off staying with Flash.

Becoming more familier with Silverlight yourself would help you to explain the strengths of SilverLight and all the good things. Time for that Hello World Silverlight app to be created.

Comment: The features of Flash apps are well known for everybody, but not everybody knows what Silverlight is about.
As I said, I have a list of prons of SL as a .NET developer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things that you can do in Flash/Air can be done in Silverlight and vice versa. even if they are some things you can do in one but not the other, they might not be applicable to your scenario. picking the tool is one task. Assuming you have picked Silverlight then comes the difficult task do you use Code Behind, MVP, MVC, MVVM, Prism, Caliburn, SLExtensions. and once you pick the pattern you use, you will soon find there are n-variations of each with no definitive guidance

I would say if dev's are familiar with .net go with Silverlight

Comment: Yep. There is a long way to make anything production-ready..

Answer (score 0):

I met the CEO of this company on Tuesday, so I have no prior affiliation or vested interest.  (But, he was a nice enough guy, so I'll give him this free plug.)  Both the apps you see on this page are pretty cool, and the first is a Silverlight app.

http://www.atamagroup.com/